# Monthly Time series in R

Tags: r, histogram, time-series

I have a data frame of 2M unix timestamps and I want to make a monthly histogram of that. Any suggestions? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `DF` is our test data then take the mean over all data points having the same year and month giving zoo object `z` and plot it:

```
# test data
DF <- data.frame(Time = as.POSIXct(Sys.Date() + 1:1000), data = 1:1000)

library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(DF, aggregate = mean, FUN = as.yearmon)
plot(z, type = "h")
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfect. To make the histogram I assined '1' to 'data' and set aggregate=sum

Answer (score 0):

Parse them (e.g. via `as.POSIXct()`) so that you proper DateTime objects.

Then use an aggregation routine, and e.g the zoo and xts packages have these for time-indexed structures, or ddply does it more generally, or you can use base R functions.

You didn't say *what* you wanted to show in the histogram. Just counts?  In that case here is a simple example:

```
R> set.seed(42)        # fix RNG
R> zz <- data.frame(val=runif(100), ts=Sys.time() - 6*31*24*60*60*runif(100))
R> summary(zz)         # values over June to Nov 2011 period
      val                 ts                        
 Min.   :0.000239   Min.   :2011-06-01 09:56:20.50  
 1st Qu.:0.259673   1st Qu.:2011-07-10 01:43:58.81  
 Median :0.539714   Median :2011-08-14 22:19:12.73  
 Mean   :0.524479   Mean   :2011-08-22 17:57:00.34  
 3rd Qu.:0.763614   3rd Qu.:2011-10-11 10:24:16.34  
 Max.   :0.988892   Max.   :2011-11-27 03:51:25.63  
R> zz$mon <- as.POSIXlt(zz$ts)$mon + 1
R> summary(zz)         # now we have the month as a column
      val                 ts                              mon       
 Min.   :0.000239   Min.   :2011-06-01 09:56:20.50   Min.   : 6.00  
 1st Qu.:0.259673   1st Qu.:2011-07-10 01:43:58.81   1st Qu.: 7.00  
 Median :0.539714   Median :2011-08-14 22:19:12.73   Median : 8.00  
 Mean   :0.524479   Mean   :2011-08-22 17:57:00.34   Mean   : 8.29  
 3rd Qu.:0.763614   3rd Qu.:2011-10-11 10:24:16.34   3rd Qu.:10.00  
 Max.   :0.988892   Max.   :2011-11-27 03:51:25.63   Max.   :11.00  
R> ddply(zz, .(mon), "nrow")   # so count rows by month
  mon nrow
1   6   17
2   7   22
3   8   18
4   9   15
5  10   14
6  11   14
R>
```

and you could do an easy histogram of those counts by month.